# Close mobile menu when clicking link in hid

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, menu

I have a mobilemenu on my website that is shown when pressing a button. Showing and hiding the menu works perfectly when I press this button with the code below:

But I also want to hide the menu when I click on a link in this menu. How can I manage to do this?

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("hamburger");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var mobilemenuspace = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (mobilemenuspace.style.display === "block") {
      mobilemenuspace.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      mobilemenuspace.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an eventLister on each of your link and then call :

```js
function onLinkClick() {
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("hamburger");
  coll.classList.remove("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add event listeners to each of the links. The code could look something like the following.

Note, to me, the code below is cumbersome and at places unclear or unsafe, *which is fine*, it's a good start. jQuery can make things a little better, but it would be neater in React or Vue.

```js
const toggleMenu = () => {
  const menu = document.getElementsByClassName("the-list")[0];
  if (typeof menu === "undefined" || typeof menu === "null") {
    throw new Error("menu element not found");
  };

  const isHidden = menu.classList.contains("hidden");
  if (isHidden) {
    menu.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    menu.classList.add("hidden");
  };
};

const button = document.getElementById("the-button");
button.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

const links = document.getElementsByClassName("a-link");
for (link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="the-list hidden">
  <li class="a-link"><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li class="a-link"><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>
<button id="the-button">toggle menu</button>
```